# Is there a way to customize dired so that it exclusively shows the file size, as well as the month and day of creation, for each item in the listing?

Tags: dired

I've added an image to provide visual clarity. The portion highlighted in red is the area I intend to keep.

[image]

I'm aware that there's a method to completely remove all detailed information and display only the folder names – a practice I've observed many emacs users adopting. However, I'm not interested in that approach. I would like to have all the detailed information display when pressing `(`, though, which is bound to `dired-hide-details-mode`.

I currently have these flags enabled:

```
(dired-listing-switches "-agho --group-directories-first"))
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: (1) Likely depends on your `ls` command's options - `M-x man ls`, or on what `ls-lisp.el` offers, if you use that. It's not a Dired thing per se. (2) `(` is a *toggle* in Dired; it's quick to show/hide everything. Do you really care that when "everything" is shown it shows only what you describe? I leave everything hidden till I want to see some particular info (then hide everything again).